# read and execute commands from text file

Tags: php

I have a txt file with all the sql commands. I need to open the file, read the commands and execute against postgresql.

```
$file = fopen("createme.sql.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file))
  {
  pg_query($conn, fgets($file));
  }
fclose($file);
```

I expected the above code to work. But is shows an error:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed:
```

How do I execute the commands from a text file?

Comment: Maybe you should split your question in 1) how to read lines from a file 2) how to execute string as commands. As for the second question you could try shell_exec (string $cmd), exec(string $cmd) and also ‛command‛ should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` get file content line by line.

Using `fread` to get all content of file, set the second parameter to size of your files.

```
$fileName = "createme.sql.txt";
$file = fopen($fileName, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

// checking if opening file is error.
if(!feof($file))
  {
  $str = fread($file, filesize($fileName));
  pg_query($conn, $str);
  }
fclose($file);
```

Another trick thanks to @smassey

```
$fileName = "createme.sql.txt";
$str = file_get_contents($fileName);
pg_query($conn, $str);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: or even simpler.. ( no need for the while loop if you immediately read till the end of the file ): pg_query( file_get_contents( $file ) );

Answer (score 0):

try `trim()` to cutoff `"\r\n"` from the end of each line

```
$file = fopen("createme.sql.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file))
  {
  pg_query($conn, trim(fgets($file)));
  }
fclose($file);
```